# Cannot POST to OneNote Client

Tags: onenote-api, microsoft-graph-api

I cannot avoid getting the following error :

```
StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
```

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<string> SendPostRequest(string _AccessToken)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _AccessToken);

        string date = GetDate();
        string simpleHtml = "<html>" +
                            "<head>" +
                            "<title>A simple page created from basic HTML-formatted text</title>" +
                            "<meta name=\"created\" content=\"" + date + "\" />" +
                            "</head>" +
                            "<body>" +
                            "<p>This is a page that just contains some simple <i>formatted</i> <b>text</b></p>" +
                            "<p>Here is a <a href=\"http://www.microsoft.com\">link</a></p>" +
                            "</body>" +
                            "</html>";

        var createMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _GraphAPIEndpoint)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(simpleHtml, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html")
        };

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(createMessage);

        return response.ToString();


    }
```

Here is the GraphEndpoint:

```
private string _GraphAPIEndpoint ="https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/pages";
```

Everything looks good with the login and authentication.  I get a token etc.

Here is the code for getting my token:

```
 private const string _ClientID = "981c0157-69ec-4f42-8ec6-xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
       public static PublicClientApplication clientApplication = new PublicClientApplication(_ClientID);

       private AuthenticationResult authResult = null;

       authResult = await App.clientApplication.AcquireTokenAsync(_Scopes);
            if (authResult != null)
            {
               string response = await SendPostRequest(authResult.AccessToken);

            }
```

Comment: What platform are you working on? ASP.NET? Windows store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following combination finally works:

```
 private string graphAPIEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages";

    private string[] scopes = new string[] { "Notes.ReadWrite" };
```

It would have been easier if some of the github OneNote Samples would have been updated.

Answer (score 1):

How are you obtaining your token?

If you're obtaining your token through login.microsoftonline.com, then try posting to

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages

It seems you're using C# - I'd recommend looking at the samples we have, and using them as a reference.

https://github.com/OneNoteDev/MsGraph_OneNoteApiSampleAspNetCore
https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleWinUniversal

The Live SDK is deprecated - you shouldn't use it. I recommend the following for you then: developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/code-samples-and-sdks Microsoft Graph SDKs and samples span many platforms and use latest, supported authentication frameworks. With those, you can call POST ~/pages (there's even SDK support)

Comment: Here is the code for obtaining the token. It is a modification of the MSAL_Authentication github code.

Comment: i've used both EndPoints and get and Error 401:       ////Set the API Endpoint
          //   string _GraphAPIEndpoint = https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/pages";
             string _GraphAPIEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages";

Comment: I'd recommend using our code samples as a reference.

Comment: It would be perfect if the MSAL Authentication github sample would post a page to OneNote.  That would be exactly what I am trying to do.  However, my MSAL sample Gets email addresses. :(

Comment: Jorge, Thanks for the advice.  If the OneNoteAPISampleWinUniversal wasn't three years old and used MSAL rather than LiveSDK, I don't think I would be having so much trouble.:)

Comment: The Live SDK is deprecated - you shouldn't use it... Fair point.I recommend the following for you then:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/code-samples-and-sdks
Microsoft Graph SDKs and samples span many platforms and use latest, supported authentication frameworks. With those, you can call POST ~/pages (there's even SDK support).

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint does not look correct. It should be either be as provided by Jorge above or if you are hitting OneNote API directly, it should be: "https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/pages"

Comment: I still get the Error 401 after added the EndPoint you suggested.  Here are some of the EndPoints I have used and all give Error 401 @Jorge Aquirre.  When I use the Live SDK I can post to the OneNote page with no problem.  It is only when converting to the Microsoft.Identity.Client that I have problems.  Here are the endpoints: 'code'

Comment: ////Set the API Endpoint
          //   string _GraphAPIEndpoint = "https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/pages";
          //   string _GraphAPIEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages";
            string _GraphAPIEndpoint = "https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/pages";

Comment: Can you share the X-CorrelationId header from your 401 response?

Comment: StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  
  X-RoutingCorrelationId: 27b2a828-0593-45bd-844b-54e542ebefa3
  X-OfficeCluster: wus-000.apimonolith.onenote.com
  P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONi TELi CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDi OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR"
  X-RoutingOfficeVersion: 16.0.8425.1559
  Cache-Control: private
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  Date: Fri, 28 Jul 2017 01:10:14 GMT

  X-CorrelationId: 27b2a828-0593-45bd-844b-54e542ebefa3

Comment: btw, I've watched Manjusha's Channel 9 video many times. My code works with Live SDK, but because it is "deprecated" Im spinning my wheels trying to get it to work with MSAL..Microsoft.Identiry.Client,  So it goes.